# How to get spinner value sent to the next page?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-spinner

Need immediate answer..

```
sem.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sems = sem.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

and then this

```
pasa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Starting a new Intent
        Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), semis.class);
        //Sending data to another Activity

        nextScreen.putExtra("semss", sems.toString());

        finish();
        startActivity(nextScreen);
    }
});
```

im having difficulties.. an error.. my emulator is forced close after i clicked the button.. what should i do?
Thanks

Comment: immediately post your error details from logcat

Comment: you finished your activity before starting another one in pasa.setOnclickListener ...

Answer (score 0):

You should call finish() after starting the new activity, not before.

Like this:

```
pasa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Starting a new Intent
        Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), semis.class);
        //Sending data to another Activity

        nextScreen.putExtra("semss", sems.toString());
        startActivity(nextScreen);
        finish();

    }
});
```

Comment: can you share what you see in logcat? so we can understand in which line you are getting an error

Answer (score 0):

```
pasa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Starting a new Intent
        Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), semis.class);
        //Sending data to another Activity
        nextScreen.putExtra("semss", sems.toString());
        startActivity(nextScreen);
        finish();  // this is the last statement ever
    }
});
```

Comment: it is still forced closed